# Apache2 reverse proxy to access multiple lan servers from wan

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, reverse-proxy, web-applications, apache2

I've got about 5 web applications on different servers running on my LAN, which are all listening to port 80

I would like to make them accessible from the internet by setting up an Apache reverse proxy on my main webserver, which is running on Ubuntu 16.04

Changing their ports and then portfordwarding is not a really good option, since there are a bunch of devices that would need reconfiguration. Plus I would like to keep it user friendly, manually writing ports isn't

So basically, I want to redirect requests the following way:

`www.mydomain.com/server3` should redirect to `192.168.1.3:80`

`www.mydomain.com/server4` should redirect to `192.168.1.4:80`

And so on

For now, I followed these instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

After installing and enabling the requeried modules, I added the following lines to the  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf' file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On

# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example:
ProxyPass "/server3" "http://192.168.1.3:80"
ProxyPassReverse "/server3" "http://192.168.1.3:80"

ServerName pacs
</VirtualHost>
```

But it didn't have any effect, same goes for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.3:80
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.3:80

ServerName pacs
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive `ProxyPass "/server3" "http://192.168.1.3:80"`  does not need the default port number 80 for HTTP and I would add a trailing slash:
`ProxyPass "/server3/" "http://192.168.1.3/`.

As of the the 2.4 release the [manual recommends](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) the functionally identical syntax with the ProxyPass directive enclosed in a `<Location>` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName pacs
     <Location /server3/>
          ProxyPass "http://192.168.1.3/"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://192.168.1.3/"
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

after restarting requests to `http://pacs/server3/` should now be forwarded to 192.168.1.3, check the access log there to see them come in.

Note: If the content on 192.168.1.3 for instance refers to /css/style.css your browser will interpret that and make a request to `http://pacs/css/style.css`  which most likely fails as that resource is not covered by the reverse proxy.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what "ServerName" actually stands for
I'm running tests in a lan server, which doesn't have a domain name pointing to it. Right now I'm trying to forward requests from 172.16.1.22/server3 to 192.168.1.3 
Both leaving ServeName blank, and using the actual ip won't work. A reference to a .css doesn't seem to be the problem, as I tried changing 192.168.1.3 to something like google.com with no luck

Comment: Got it to work using 172.16.1.22 as the servername, and typing 172.16.122/server3/ instead of 172.16.122/server3
I've got another problem going now, but that's a whole different story
Thank you a lot!